# how to configure application using XACML using identity server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

1. please help me out with example that how can we configure application using XACML using WSO2 Identity Server.

Answer (score 2):

This documentation [1] provides the steps to configure a XACML access control policy for a service provider (application) with WSO2 IS 5.7.0. Also you can refer this comprehensive blog [2] which contains lots of articles on XACML use cases with WSO2 Identity Server.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Access+Control+Policy+for+a+Service+Provider
[2] http://xacmlinfo.org/category/xacml/